# How to copy only wanted child nodes along with it's parent using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0

This is XSLT

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" >
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="pathneeded" select="'catalog/cd1,catalog/Test/value/a1’” />
<xsl:variable name ="xpaths">
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($pathneeded,',')">
<item>
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</item>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:call-template name="printpath">
 <xsl:with-param name="paths" select = "$xpaths" />
  <xsl:with-param name="count" select = "1" />
</xsl:call-template>
<!-- <xsl:evaluate xpath="$pathneeded" context-item="."/> -->
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name = "printpath" >
  <xsl:param name = "paths" />  
  <xsl:param name = "count" />
  <xsl:variable name="total" select = "count($paths/item)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="path" select = "$paths/item[$count]"/>
  <xsl:evaluate xpath="$path" context-item="."/>
  <xsl:if test="$count &lt; $total">
<xsl:call-template name="printpath">
 <xsl:with-param name="paths" select = "$paths" />
  <xsl:with-param name="count" select = "$count + 1" />
</xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is My Input

```html
<catalog>
<cd1>
<name>abc</name>
<Stext>1234</Stext>
<Tag>uuuu</Tag>
</cd1>
<cd2>
<name>abc</name>
<Stext>1234</Stext>
<Tag>uuuu</Tag>
</cd2>
<Test>
<value>
 <a1>123</a1>
<b1>77474</b1>
</value>
</Test>
</catalog>
```

Below is expected output

```html
<catalog>
<cd1>
<name>abc</name>
<Stext>1234</Stext>
<Tag>uuuu</Tag>
</cd1>
<Test>
<value>
 <a1>123</a1>
</value>
</Test>
</catalog>
```

Currently i am working with xslt 3.0 and below xslt is not copying the parent node so any help is much appreciated.

I tried with identity template but couldn't figure out the solution so planned to create custom template

Comment: See whether you can use the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817187/252228

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817187/252228 using a static parameter, with a normal string parameter you can use `xsl:evaluate` where supported (e.g. Saxon-JS 2, Saxon 10 all editions, Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 PE or EE):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="pathneeded" as="xs:string" select="'catalog/cd1,catalog/Test/value/a1'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="nodes" as="node()*">
    <xsl:evaluate xpath="$pathneeded" context-item="/"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:variable name="ancestors" select="$nodes/ancestor::*"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="$nodes">
    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="$ancestors">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: while loading this xslt form my java source i am facing below issue:XPTY0004: An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of variable $multiplexpaths. I updated the xslt with below two lines                                                                                                    
 <xsl:param name="multiplexpaths" as="xs:string" static="yes" />
 <xsl:variable name="nodes" _select="{$multiplexpaths}"/>

Comment: The code I posted does not use a variable `$multiplexpaths`. If you have a new problem after adapting an answer, ask a new separate question with a complete samples of what you have tried instead of throwing new code into a comment to an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860631/xpty0004-an-empty-sequence-is-not-allowed-as-the-value-of-variable-while-loadin

Comment: created a new question.. Thank you