# XPTY0004: An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of variable while loading xslt using saxon templatefactory

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I updated the provided xslt to accept a param "multiplexpaths"  from my source and assignin enter code here`g this to nodes variable in xslt to below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:param name="multiplexpaths" as="xs:string" static="yes" />
  <!--  xsl:param name="copy" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'//other[. = 1345], //more[. = 2]'"/-->

  <xsl:variable name="nodes" _select="{$multiplexpaths}"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ancestors" select="$nodes/ancestor::*"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="$nodes">
    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="$ancestors">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A static parameter needs some initialization so if you declare `xs:string` as its type you will need to select a default string. I am not sure you want that but it is not clear exactly what you want to achieve and where/how you want to set the parameter.

Comment: I am trying to run the xslt solution provided using a small java code where i am using saxon9.9.6jar and setting parameter to the transformer object.

Comment: If needed i can post the sample java code that i am using

Comment: It is a static parameter, the JAXP `Transformer` object was designed for XSLT 1, I think if you use Saxon 9 and want to use advanced XSLT 2 or 3 features it is easier and sometimes necessary to use Saxon's s9api https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.html where you can set static parameters before compilation with https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XsltCompiler.html#setParameter-net.sf.saxon.s9api.QName-net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmValue- on the XsltCompiler.

Comment: Can you share any samples how i can achieve it using saxon

Answer (score 0):

For the `xsl:evaluate` example, you would need to use Saxon 10 HE, 9.9 HE doesn't support `xsl:evaluate`.

As for setting a static parameter with Saxon 9.9 and s9api, a simple example is

```
    String paths = "catalog/cd1,catalog/Test/value/a1";
    
    Processor processor = new Processor(true);
    
    XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
    
    xsltCompiler.setParameter(new QName("copy"), new XdmAtomicValue(paths));
    
    XsltExecutable xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.compile(new StreamSource("static-param-example2.xsl"));
    
    Xslt30Transformer xslt30Transformer = xsltExecutable.load30();
    
    xslt30Transformer.transform(new StreamSource("input-sample1.xml"), xslt30Transformer.newSerializer(System.out));
```

with the input-sample1.xml being

```
<catalog>
    <cd1>
        <name>abc</name>
        <Stext>1234</Stext>
        <Tag>uuuu</Tag>
    </cd1>
    <cd2>
        <name>abc</name>
        <Stext>1234</Stext>
        <Tag>uuuu</Tag>
    </cd2>
    <Test>
        <value>
            <a1>123</a1>
            <b1>77474</b1>
        </value>
    </Test>
</catalog>
```

and the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="copy" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'()'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="nodes" _select="{$copy}"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ancestors" select="$nodes/ancestor::*"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="$nodes">
    <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="$ancestors">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this outputs

```
<catalog>
   <cd1>
      <name>abc</name>
      <Stext>1234</Stext>
      <Tag>uuuu</Tag>
   </cd1>
   <Test>
      <value>
         <a1>123</a1>
      </value>
   </Test>
</catalog>
```

So the main point is to set the parameter on the XsltCompiler and not after compilation on the transformer.

Comment: Tried above but facing: Static error in {xs:string} at char 0 in expression in xsl:param/@as on line 6 column 67 of static-param-example2.xslt:
  XPST0051  Unknown simple type xs:string
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Unknown simple type xs:string

Comment: Similarly do we have any capability in xslt3.0 that can exclude certain xpaths that we can set to parameter.Currently i am using capability of Identity template but the performance is verylow

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: posted new question below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977263/remove-certain-nodes-from-an-xml-using-xslt3-0